# Entries order in /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, interface, dhcp

I have a device with two interfaces, eth0 and eth1. One should get its IP from a DHCP server and the other should get its IP statically.

If my `/etc/network/interfaces` file is configured as follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
iface eth1 inet6 auto

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.10.10.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Everything works great, eth1 gets its IP from the DHCP server, eth0 sets its IP statically from the information given, but if I try to change the order in the file, such as

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.10.10.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
iface eth1 inet6 auto
```

In this case, eth1 fails to get an IP.

Does the /etc/network/interface care about the order of each interfaces, such that the admin should place the interfaces that get IPs through DHCP first, then the static ones, or is there a different error in the configuration I have made?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Is this Ubuntu or Debian?

Comment: It's a Debian. But as far as I know Ubuntu is a Debian distribution.

Comment: Which version? The interface was changed in newer versions.

Comment: I have a repro on Ubuntu17.04. Might be a known issue. Need to check with Debian. In any case, this question should probably be on another SE site, maybe Unix & Linux.

Comment: It's an older version and it's a custom one. I'll post this question on Unix&Linux as well. Thanks

Comment: I found this bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=779681 which says dhcp is unconfiguring previous configurations. Might be related. Other than that I don't see anything related in the list of debian bugs for ifupdown package: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?repeatmerged=yes&src=ifupdown